# Secure WebSockets with Socket.io, Node.js, and iisnode

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, iisnode

I have an application that works perfectly fine with websockets through iisnode to a Node.js/Express/Socket.io application.

> Windows Server 2012
>   iisnode 2.21
>   IIS 8.5
>   Node 6.2.1
>   socket.io 1.4.8
>   express.js 4.14

When visiting via HTTPS, however, WebSockets are falling back to polling after a seemingly *successful* wss negotiation:

```
GET wss://x.com/socket/a145e1f7-c8e7-4b26-96d3-a4d9869b5f3a/?id=a145e1f7-c8e7-4b26-96d3-a4d9869b5f3a&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=2nKT2dHWKrmO5xaHAAAM HTTP/1.1
Host: x.com
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: https://x.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: io=2AAAM; _ga=GA1.2.452745265.1462472455; connect.sid=s%3M8aVwM; rl-sticky-key=!1z8WBml+V4=
Sec-WebSocket-Key: qocdK/MRQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Connection: Upgrade
sec-websocket-accept: VOFznVr/l4fsY=
sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2016 18:20:04 GMT
```

But there are no frames in this WebSocket, and Socket.io returns to HTTP polling. If TLS is handled by IIS, how could WebSockets be effected after wss protocol negotiation?

Comment: I'm attempting this same solution, iisnode, and socketio, the issue I'm getting is setting up the routing. Did you have any good examples showing this in iis or iisnode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there were load balancer problems that caused this issue, nothing that the technology software stack was doing wrong.